# Best way to make CSS scale to mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone provide some tips as to how I can make my CSS effectively scale down to a proper document layout when viewed/resized to a mobile viewport?

I remember reading about using percentages on CSS boxes but I cannot get things to stack correctly when I've tried this.

Any help would be great!

Comment: -1  We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: @iambriansreed If the question needs to be shut, you're supposed to downvote the question, not the answers. You do know that right?

Comment: This is an extremely broad topic. Start by searching for "responsive web design", read some of the dozens and dozens of good tutorials and blog posts, and then come back here when you've got some code to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read up on [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries). These allow you to set conditional styles for screens above/below certain widths, heights, and aspect ratios.

As others have mentioned, there are a number of responsive grid frameworks (see jmeas' answer) which can handle this for you. Whether you want to use them will depend on your deployment requirements and how much you want to customize your layouts.

Comment: Perfect, thats what I will do then. Thank you for your response. It was more of an inquiry towards current best practice vs. a problem really. Thanks!

Comment: @BennyP Glad that's what you were looking for, then! I've found media queries immensely useful in my work, and with the current trend toward a mobile web they're a very valuable tool to know your way around.

Answer (score 5):

metadept's answer is, as far as I know, the best way to go about this. But as with most things, you shouldn't reinvent the wheel when you don't need to. And it happens that there are good CSS frameworks for building responsive websites using media queries. My personal favorite is [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). Of particular interest to you is [the Scaffolding section.](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)

By just appending the right classes to your elements, you can rearrange things in various display modes (desktop, tablet, etc.), and it automatically does some pretty intelligent things with the layout by default.

Other good choices (thanks to metadept for suggesting I add these) are the [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and the [960 Grid System](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2133379/metadept).

With any of these frameworks, don't forget to add this to your `head`!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This forces the webpage to display at the width of many modern smart phones.

Comment: As far as frameworks go, I think Zurb Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/) and 960 Grid System (http://960.gs/) are also worth mentioning.

Comment: Good suggestions, I'll add them to my answer!

Comment: I have to agree with @metadept Foundation is by far the most powerful and easy to use framework I've come across (in my opinion).

Comment: Why the downvote on my answer? (and, for that matter, the other two?)